# Effective Dart warns about avoiding forEach. Use build in for-in instead

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

Effective Dart warns about avoiding forEach. Use build in for-in instead.

[Please click this link](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal)

Is there any better way? I want to `wait` and `return`.

```
 List<PromotionModel> allPromotion = //add data from api;

 Future<List<PromotionModel>> filterPromotion() async {
    List<PromotionModel> temp = [];
    if(!check){
      return allPromotion;
    }else{
      await Future.forEach(allPromotion, (v) async {
        if(v.vendoruid == uid){
          temp.add(v);
        }
      });
      return temp;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's the field type of `allPromotion`?

Comment: `allPromotion` type is function type... -> `List<PromotionModel>`

Comment: they say about `Iterable.forEach` not about `Future.forEach` - btw why do you need `Future.forEach` in your case? why dont you simply use `Iterable.where`?

Comment: @pskink I need to wait until loop finished and then I need to return `temp`. that's why I used. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `allPromotion` is of `Future<List>` type, just `await` the future and loop through the provided list like so:

```
final list = await allPromotion;
for (var v in list) {
  if (v.vendoruid == uid) {
    temp.add(v);
  }
}
return temp;
```

Comment: please check again my question... I forgot to add type of `allPromotion`

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but `allPromotion` isn't of `Future` type so why are you using `Future.forEach()`?

Comment: otherwise, return an empty value without a complete loop.. isn't it?